# How can I see and close active software manager processes?

Tags: update-manager

I use the Lubuntu 14.04 version on my eeepc netbook. To install Skype, I downloaded the package and I'm using the "Installatore applicazioni" (in english, "Package installer" I guess). Before starting the installation, it says

"Only one software management tool is allowed to run at the same time.
Please close the other application (e.g. Update Manager, aptitude, or synaptic) first."

How can I close the Update Manager (or one of the others)?
And, in general, how can I know which processes are active and how to close them? I mean, the analogous for the Windows ctrl-alt-canc in Lubuntu (if it ever exists)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Different tools exist for checking active processes.

## `ps` command

This command allows to get a list of active processes, along with other information. Usually it is used with `ax` parameters (to see all processes) together with `grep` as a filter, for example:

```
ps ax | grep -i apt
```

In this case `-i` means case-insensitive match. This will show process ids, e.g.:

```
andrea@farore:~$ ps ax | grep -i apt
24036 pts/5    S+     0:00 sudo apt-get update
24037 pts/5    S+     0:00 apt-get update
24040 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
24041 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
24042 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
24043 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
24044 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
24046 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
24066 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2
24069 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -i apt
andrea@farore:~$
```

You can then kill individual processes by issuing a `kill` command:

```
kill -9 24036
```

The number `9` is the signal, in this case `SIGKILL` (which means a brutal interruption). A more "nice" signal is `SIGTERM` which corresponds to `15`. For more information on signals, see the manpage:

```
man 7 signal
```

## `top` command

This command shows an interactive view of active processes, also showing process numbers. They are usually sorted by CPU usage.

[image: top command]

When you know the process number, you can kill it as said before.

## `htop` command

This process manager is not installed by default, but it's available in the standard repositories. It is similar to `top`, but has easy keyboard shortcuts such as `F6` for sorting and `F9` for killing.

[image: htop command]

## System monitor

Finally, you can find the "System monitor" application in the Unity dash, which shows a very basic list of running processes and allows to kill them. Similar tools with similar names exist in all Ubuntu derivatives. In any case, IMHO the aforementioned CLI tools are faster.

[image: system monitor]

Comment: Sorry, while answering I didn't pay attention to the fact that you are running Lubuntu, so the last tip is more related to Unity users. Anyway, the CLI commands I mentioned are still available.